# Need to create http webserver using Qt 4.7 in C++

Tags: c++, http, qt4, webserver

I need to create a http web server which responds to http clients using Qt 4.7
I have gone through the API and found few servers, but how to create a http server using the API
Any hints and guidance on this please....i am totally new to this

also what is .pro in Qt 4.7 and is it the same as doing in Visual studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `QTcpServer` , check this [`example`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtservice/qtservice-example-server.html).

Comment: thanks a lot for the resource...i am doing this on VS08 so how diff it is from building using a .pro file

Comment: That is unrelated, pro files are all the same for all platforms. Just generate a Visual studio project with `qmake -t vcapp project.pro -o project.vcproj` and open `project.vcproj` with Visual Studio.

Comment: in the demo example they are using QCoreApplication and QtService which i am unable to find any library in include directory

Comment: QtService is 3rd party library you shouldn't use it, QCoreApplication comes default with Qt.

Comment: getting some link errors are there any settings i need to take care even after installing the plugin for VS08..    error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000027) "public: bool __thiscall QBasicAtomicInt::operator==(int)const " (??8QBasicAtomicInt@@$$FQBE_NH@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall QList<class QString>::free(struct QListData::Data *)" (?free@?$QList@VQString@@@@$$FAAEXPAUData@QListData@@@Z)

Answer (score 3):

QtWebApp is a HTTP 1.1 server based on QTcpServer. It supports GET and POST method, file uploads, cookies and sessions.