# Audio stream server (from a cross platform server to any device)

Tags: qt, stream, streaming, shoutcast

This is not a specific coding question but more a research project.

I am very interested in streaming services. To be more specific, I am interested in streaming audio from a server to a device. I do understand the basic logic behind it but I want to get better knowledge in these things.

I would like to try implementing a streaming server and a streaming client (server on mac and client on iOS) but I am having some trouble finding any pages that offer "tutorials" on how its done. I have managed to get the client side somehow and in its example it is playing stream from `shoutmedia`. How can I implement the server side? I would prefer it in C++ (server in Qt for example would be a bullseye) but any links will be appreciated.

I think that streaming is quite an interesting topic and any links will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: SHOUTcast/Icecast servers are essentially HTTP.  If you want to make a server for that, build an HTTP server that streams data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561140/need-to-create-http-webserver-using-qt-4-7-in-c